punctuation: comma in [requirement, at least]
(1a) For this job, there is a speed requirement, at least sixty words per minute.
(1b) For this job, there is a speed requirement of at least sixty words per minute.
Most of my non-native friends think using a comma before "at least" is wrong. Why is it wrong?

Your 1a does need some punctuation mark after requirement. But better than the comma would be a colon. When used in a sentence like this, the colon separates a label or description (here “a speed requirement”) from the thing that is labeled or described (here “at least sixty words per minute”). Compare to Adam and Eve had two sons: Cain and Abel.

1a needs a comma.  The part after the comma is an interruption and is removable. If we remove this interruption,  we get the shortened 1a, which is fine:
For this job, there is a speed requirement.
It would be ungrammatical without the comma:
1a. *For this job, there is a speed requirement at least sixty words per minute.
Now the part after requirement is to serve as a postmodifier of this noun and needs of.
That would give us 1b.
